# PHP user friendly URL creation

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wamp

I have an issue regarding the user friendly URL of the website.

In general the URL is like this, http://domain.com/abc.php?id=1. 
But I wish to get like this, http://domain.com/abc/id/1

I know .htaccess helps us to do so. Here is my code for same.

```
[htaccess]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteRule ^application/index$ application/index.php
RewriteRule ^application/about$ application/about.php
RewriteRule ^application/contact$ application/contact.php
[/htaccess]
```

This is working fine. But there is another issue. Each page has got individual rewrite rule. My question are below.

1. Whether its possible to make it with single rewrite rule, so that I no need to write for other pages. I wish to write one rewrite rules and it works for all URLs.
2. Am I need to do anything with .php pages? Am I need to write any special function to get extract, read and write URLs?
3. I am working in the WAMP server for test purpose. Then I upload the file to the server. Is it necessary to update the file for server?

Please help to cope up the issues.

Regards & Thanks.

Comment: There are about 56389365483 examples for this on SO and on the internet in general. All these did not help? Then I suggest you take a look into the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html I am not trying to be picky here. It is just that you need to read the documentation anyway to learn about the features of the tools you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of naming each and every .php file you can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

thanks for the reply. Its working. Can you provide me some resources to understand and apply .htaccess with php, especially mod_rewrite condition and rules including specification given inside []?

Comment: http://askapache.com is pretty good resource to learn url rewriting using Apache.